# When I use the spotify api to search for a song, and print the response, it is always showing response code[502]

Tags: python, response, spotify

Here is the code for it

```
from urllib import parse
import os
import requests
api_token = os.getenv('SPOTIFY_AUTH_TOKEN')

query = parse.quote('Hardwell Power')
url = f'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q={query}&type=track'
response = requests.get(
    url,
    headers={
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {api_token}'
    }

)
print(response)
```

Here is the output

```
<Response [502]>
```

Can anyone please point out the mistake and help me?

Answer (score 0):

To get the other stuff from response try using `print(response.json())` or `print(response.text)`

Comment: you mean add `response.json()` inside print?

Comment: yes, since Response code isn't 200 you won't be getting anything useful. Use `print(response.reason)` to find what is wrong

Comment: this is what I get when I print `response.text`

<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>502 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>

Comment: on doing `print(response.reason)` it says "Bad Request"

Comment: https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.16.1/   are you using this library ?

Comment: no no I ain't using spotipy or any library related to spotify

Comment: try using it, its better to use a specific library

Comment: okay that can be done, but I wanna do it without any spotify library, using only the spotify api, is there a way you could do it??

Comment: read through this https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/quick-start/